# Update value of a nested key by reference in python 3

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I have the following dictionary:

```
  watch_list=  {'videos': [{'systemId': 'qre', 'duration': 19}, {'systemId': 'abc', 'duration': 19}]}
```

now I wanted to check if the systemId already exists in the dictionary and if yes then update duration by systemId.

hence I am trying the following code:

```
def update_duration(watch_list,system_id,duration):
watch_history= next((a for a in watch_list if a['systemId'] == system_id), None)
if watch_history:
    watch_history['duration'] =duration
    return watch_history
```

but this gives me an error:

```
*** TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am new to python, I have read stack overflow other solutions but couldnt made it work. can anyone help me a little here, on how to update the value by the systemId?

I am using python 3 and flask

Comment: `watch_list` is not a dictionary, but a list with one string.

Comment: As Devesh said you are working with a `str` not a `dict`.  You can convert it to a `dict` with `json.loads(myDict)` and fix other logic or search through the string to find `duration` and `systemId` to manually get the value

Comment: its not string (Pdb) type(watch_list)
<class 'dict'>
its dict

Comment: (Pdb) print(watch_list)
{'videos': [{'systemId': 'qre', 'duration': 19}, {'systemId': 'abc', 'duration': 19}]}
here is the full output

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through a dictionary with something like

```py
my_dictionary = { 'hello' : ['I', 'am', 'a', 'dictionary'] }

for entry in my_dictionary:
    print entry
```

The output will be `hello`, as it iterates through its keys by default. As it appears you're actually wanting to iterate through the dictionary's values, you'll want to call the `values()` function, or `itervalues()` in Python2.

Beyond that, you're then running into an issue with your generator comprehension's if statement. At that point, your `a` variable is holding a list of dictionaries---what used to be the value found by `watch_list['videos']`.

Comment: if i['systemId'] == system_id: if i do this i end up with this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str :(

Comment: Exactly, that's what the last paragraph of my answer is talking about. At that point, `a` == `[{'systemId': 'qre', 'duration': 19}, {'systemId': 'abc', 'duration': 19}]`.